# How to reset stack in react native navigation v5

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am looking for ways to reset or clear the nested stack in TabBar in react-native navigation 5 which latest. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

you can either use `navigation.popToTop()`, if you just want to reset to the first screen, or if you want to set a different route at the top of the stack you can use:

```
navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    routes: [
      {name: YOUR_ROUTE_NAME},
    ],
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In react navigation v5 or above, i got working by doing following logic:
Reset navigation history after login/logout
Here screenOrStack should be screen name within stack, or if you want to navigate to other stack so it should be that stack name.

ex: 1) on login after auth check, call this function with DashboardStack

2. on logout operation call this with Loginstack

   ```
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(
        CommonActions.reset({
            index: 0,
            routes: [{ name: screenOrStack_name }],
        })
    );
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
navigation.reset({
  routes: [{ name: 'Login' }]
});
```